# Listview base adapter getview skips position

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

As the title says my adapter's getView method will sometimes skip a position. I haven't been able to determine why it happens, but from putting breakpoints on the adapter I have noticed that the getItemViewType does get called but getView doesn't always get called. It is my understanding that getItemViewType gets called and then getView gets called, but maybe I'm missing something?

I overriding getViewTypeCount, getItemViewType, getCount, and getItem

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isMe() ? ME : OTHER;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // Left or right bubble
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messages.getCount();
}

@Override
public HsConversationMessageItem getItem(int position) {
    // Reverse the order of the items since we want the newest items on the bottom
    return messages.getItem(getCount() - position - 1);
}
```

What is supposed to happens is that getItemViewType gets called for position x, then getView gets called for that same position. But sometimes getItemViewType gets called for position x, skips getView and getItemViewType gets called again for x+1, and the rest continues as normal. For what it's worth I don't think that the problem is with my getView method, since it doesn't get called.

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "skip a position"? And why do you need that positions are not "skipped"?

Comment: So  `getItemViewType(int position)` gets called for let's say position 49, the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method doesn't get with position 49, it will get called for position 48. Does that make sense? I know it's a weird problem so it's hard to explain.

Comment: Can you add your getView(...) code?

Comment: Ok, I get it. Why do you need it? What are you trying to achieve? Or is it just for knowledge?

Comment: I'm building a messaging app. When this happens it will duplicate the last row on the listview, it also causes a null pointer if the user click on the last message received. Now I know I can fix the index out of bounds exception, but that is not the main problem. @taciosd I'll have to post the getView tomorrow since I'm not at work